# Deployed Application, No Display on Endpoint

Tags: angular

So I built my application to deploy So I could host it. To display it.

But I ran the command and uploaded everything inside the dist folder but nothing just a blank when opening the application

I used:

```
npm run build -- --prod

npm run build -- --prod --baseHref=/Folder/*insert AppName*
```

My index leads to root:

```
<body style="overflow-x:hidden;" class="mat-typography igx-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

My Root leads to Outlet

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Which leads to the login

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

Im a tad confused why this is happening

Edit:

When using ng build --prod

I get some errors on the page

[image]

Tested on MAMP server same thing, Just a blank screen with `Failed to load resources`  And if I navigate to index.html I get the same errors as the screenshot

Comment: Where did you deploy? What are the host redirections?

Comment: ng build --prod

Comment: @T.SunilRao A Cpanel test server I own, I usually use it for Wordpress sites

Comment: You can also try copying the /dist in an apache server in your local machine and check the deployment. It may possible that some code is causing issue in production environment. Else you need to check the network and firewall settings for your hosting server

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan I can say I have deployed a small application on this exact server before, using the --base extended command but that dint work, Its just blank tho only error I get is a 404  I can see it exported correctly in the dist folder just It doesnt display anything at all

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Got some extra errors after using the ng build when routing to the app Ill add a screenshot to avoid cluter. on my Question

Comment: Hmm... Then I think its the issue with server http routing configurations. I think the code build files are fine.

Comment: Testing on Local server Same exact thing